# What is the Unit Type Behavior in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Why does this code works:

```
val f: String => Unit = {(_:String) => 2}

//or more succinctly

val f: String => Unit = _ => 2
```

Clearly the body of my function return an int. However the type expected is Unit

But if i do

```
implicitly[String <:< Unit]

//Cannot prove that String <:< Unit.
```

Hence i am a bit confused as to how the cast is happening ? Why is it even allowed in the first place

Comment: Your function doesn't return Int, compiler takes care of it

Comment: What do you mean my function does not return Int ? clearly the body of my function does. There is an unexplained Typing here, that i would like to understand.

Comment: Basically the compiler rewrites your code like this `_ => { 2; () }` this is called **value discard**, is specified on the spec and you can disable it if you do not like it _(for pure FP code this is a nightmare, but for imperative code this is pretty useful)_

Comment: How do you disable it ? What's the option, could not find it ....

Comment: @MaatDeamon Maybe `-Wvalue-discard`/`-Ywarn-value-discard` and `-Xfatal-warnings`. https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala any type `A` can be transformed into type `Unit`. It's not subtyping, it's transforming. Like type `A` means some possible side effect plus returning `A` while `Unit` means we disregard return value but keep the side effect.

Answer (score 4):

This is called *Value Discarding*, see [*6.26.1 Value Conversions, sub-section Value Discarding*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#value-discarding) of the Scala Language Specification:

> If  has some value type and the expected type is `Unit`,  is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term `{ ; () }`.

In other words, your code is compiled *as-if* you had written

```scala
val f: String => Unit = {(_:String) => { 2; () }}

//or more succinctly

val f: String => Unit = _ => { 2; () }
```

I guess the intention behind this feature is familiarity for programmers coming from imperative programming languages, where it is often possible to discard values.

E.g. in C, it is legal to write

```c
printf("Hello");
```

and discard the return value, even though `printf` returns an `int`. This goes together with the idea of *expression statements* and *statement expressions* that many imperative programming languages have.